# How to wrap/group '<p class="p1">' , '<div class="disp-quote-p">/following-sibling::*[1][self::p[@class='p1']]' inside in single 'p' element

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I am traying to wrap the nodes `<p class="p1">' , '<div class="disp-quote-p">' and div[@class='disp-quote-p']/following-sibling::*[1][self::p[@class='p1']]` inside in single `p` element.
Input XML:-

```
<root>
    <p class="p">aa</p>
    <p class="p1">Although:</p>
    <div class="disp-quote-p">
        <p class="p">We had seen.</p>
    </div>
    <p class="p1">This dot.</p>
    <img src="a.png"/>
    <box>box</box>
    <p class="p">bb</p>
</root>
```

I am traying to blow of code for wrap the nodes in single `p` element but this node `<p class="p1">This dot.</p>` wrap with the `<div class="disp-quote-p">` node.

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="p[@class='p1']">
                <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-adjacent="self::p[@class='p1'] or self::div[@class='disp-quote-p']">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="self::p[@class='p1']">
                            <p><xsl:apply-templates select="node(), current-group() except ."/></p>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

URL Link: [http://xsltransform.net/eiov64R/1]

**Expected Output:-**

```
<root>
    <p class="p">aa</p>
    <p>Although:<disp-quote><p class="p">We had seen.</p></disp-quote>This dot.</p>
    <img src="a.png"/>
    <box>box</box>
    <p class="p">bb</p>
</root>
```

Comment: Note that, in HTML, `<p>` elements can only contain "phrasing content" and elements like `<div>` or `<p>` are not in that category. (See MDN for [`<p>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) and [phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_categories#phrasing_content).) If you attempt to do that, the browser will try to fix that invalid HTML. (I'm not sure if the XSLT would still be able to do the conversion the way your asking, but it won't stay that way after being viewed in a browser.)

Comment: @Ouroborus, I have add some elements for different scenarios this is html to xml conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!-- No need for starting with. Just begin finding the wanted adjacent elements -->
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="boolean(self::p[@class='p1'] or self::div)">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="self::p[@class='p1'] or self::div">
            <!-- Let the matching templates do the filtering -->
            <p><xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/></p>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <!-- here we filter the unwanted p -->
  <xsl:template match="p[@class='p1']">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="div[@class='disp-quote-p']">
    <xsl:element name="disp-quote">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Siebe Jongebloed - Thanks for the suggestion.